# Send email in Gmail using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to send email using Selenium , but I failed to locate the *To* field and *email body*.

This my code:

```
@Test
public  void createEmail(){

      WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://gmail.com/");

      driver.findElement(By.name("Email")).sendKeys("myUsername");;
      driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("myPassword");;
      driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      // create the Email
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.gb_7.gbii")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();   
      driver.findElement(By.name("to")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
}
```

Comment: Which exception are you getting?

Comment: It's quite difficult to send email in gmail browser version using selenium. However you can try "Basic html" version of Gmail to send mails.

Comment: Are those your real username and password in the script?

Comment: When you have more reputation, you'll be able to put comments like this where they belong: as comments on question. You could make this a real answer by editing and describing how you'd use GMail's basic HTML mode to send mail.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to send email though Gmail or you want to use Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, I found in another post.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("to")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("to").sendKeys("data");
```

The TO field is a textarea. Adding .clear() seems to set the focus correctly, maybe there are other ways to give the textarea focus first.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970240/how-to-change-text-in-textarea-with-webdriver